# ffplay low-quality, scale interpolation doesn't work

Tags: ffmpeg

acroding to ffmpeg documentation, ffmpeg uses default scale interpolation: SWS_BICUBIC
[ffplay's source code](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/ffplay.c) has a line:

```
static unsigned sws_flags = SWS_BICUBIC;
```

I have a 640x360 size h264 mp4 file: A.mp4
Compare 2 ways to diplay it:

Way 1: ffmpeg scale down A.mp4 to B.mp4 (200*122), then ffplay display B.mp4

```
ffmpeg.exe -i A.mp4 -s 200*122 B.mp4

ffplay B.mp4
```

Way 2: ffplay displays A.mp4, use mouse to resize window to 200*122

```
ffplay A.mp4
```

[comparation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f08yH.png)
[A.mp4][3]

Compare text rendering, way 1 is clearer than way 2.

I have replaced SWS_BICUBIC into other parameters in ffplay.c, cannot solve the problem.
I seems like sws_flags doens't work in ffplay, it always use a low-quality interpolation.
It's reproducible on Ubuntu and Windows with ffplay and SDL 1.2.

How to modify ffplay.c to obtain higher-quality as ffmpeg does?

ps : A.mp4 download link:
    github.com/jorp073/jorp073.github.io/blob/master/stackoverflow/A.mp4

Comment: The comparison image is plain white.

Comment: @Mulvya, re-upload a image, now you can see

Comment: Please upload the video or a full-sized frame from the video.

Comment: @Mulvya, https://github.com/jorp073/jorp073.github.io/blob/master/stackoverflow/A.mp4